# PHP mysql_fetch_array is not returning all rows - one row is always ignored

Tags: php

I am running a fairly straight forward mysql request and returning the results to a table.  There were three record in the db, and the query is pulling from two tables.  As a result, I am getting a count of three records (echoing mysql_num_rows), but only two show in the table.  Using a print_r command on the array result shows only one particular record - the other records do show in the print-r..  I added another record to the db, and now three records show - and the same record as before does not show and is the only record in the print_r command. 
Here's the relevant code:

```
<td id="page1"> 
  <?php             
    $limit  = 15;             // Set limit to show for pagination
    $page   = $_GET['page'];  // get page number from submit

    if($page) 
      $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; // first item to display on this page
    else
      $start = 0; // if no page var is given, set start to 0

    $query  = "SELECT PartyMstr.PartyMstrID, UserName, FirstName, LastName, XrefPartyRoleID
                FROM PartyMstrRole, PartyMstr
                WHERE PartyMstr.PartyMstrID = PartyMstrRole.PartyMstrID &&
                      PartyMstrRole.XrefPartyRoleID = 1 
                ORDER BY LastName, FirstName ASC
                LIMIT $start, $limit
              ";

    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalitems1 =  mysql_num_rows($result);
  ?>
  <center><h3> Admin User List </h3></center>
  <?php
    echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">";
    echo "<tr><th>PartyMaster ID</th>";
    echo "<th>UserName</th>";
    echo "<th>Last, First</th>";
    echo "<th>Link</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<tr><td>";
      echo $row['PartyMstrID'];
      echo "<td>";
      echo $row['UserName'];
      echo "<td>";
      echo " " . $row['LastName'] . ", " . $row['FirstName'] . " ";
      echo "<td>";
      echo "<a href = \"http://www.505575.com/editUser.php?id=" . $row['PartyMstrID'] . "\" >Edit</a>";

      // echo "<td>";
      // echo $row['XrefPartyRoleID'];

      echo "</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table><br/><br/> ";

    $paginaton  = getPaginationString( $page, $totalitems, $limit,
                    $adjacents  = 1,
                    $targetpage = "adminUserList.php",
                    $pagestring = "?page="
    ); // Functon found in functions.php

    echo $paginaton; 
  ?>
</td>
```

I've spent a lot of time online looking for an explanation without success.  I've switched off the `$pagination` code line without effect.  I have tried various other tricks and echoed output. The number of rows returned (`n`) is always correct, but only `n-1` rows appear in the table.  Any ideas out there?

Thanks - Don

Comment: As a clarification: did you stick do `print_r($row)` just inside your `while`-loop?

Comment: You might consider learning `PDO`, this is going to be deprecated anyways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every time you call `mysql_fetch_array` you are taking a row from the resource. When the resource has no more rows to give, it returns false. That's how `while ($a = mysql_fetch_array($resource))` loops work.

```
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());    
    $totalitems1 =  mysql_num_rows($result);

    // first row is taken from resource

    ....

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    // now take the rest of the rows
```

As you can see, your code is doing exactly what you tell it to! Just remove the first `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());` as it doesn't serve any purpose anyway.

Comment: Thank to everyone who answered - the answer is obvious once pointed out.  I checked the first of the many right answers as the correct one just for simplicities sake.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You are fetching the first result outside your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $query = "SELECT PartyMstr.PartyMstrID, UserName, FirstName, LastName, XrefPartyRoleID
        FROM PartyMstrRole, PartyMstr 
        WHERE PartyMstr.PartyMstrID = PartyMstrRole.PartyMstrID  && PartyMstrRole.XrefPartyRoleID = 1 
        ORDER BY LastName, FirstName ASC
        LIMIT $start,$limit";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());    
    $totalitems1 =  mysql_num_rows($result);
```

needs to be:

```
    $query = "SELECT PartyMstr.PartyMstrID, UserName, FirstName, LastName, XrefPartyRoleID
        FROM PartyMstrRole, PartyMstr 
        WHERE PartyMstr.PartyMstrID = PartyMstrRole.PartyMstrID  && PartyMstrRole.XrefPartyRoleID = 1 
        ORDER BY LastName, FirstName ASC
        LIMIT $start,$limit";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $totalitems1 =  mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others intimate, the problem is that you're calling `mysql_fetch_array()` once, on the line after `$result = mysql_query( ...`, before you go into your `while` loop. This takes the first row from your results, but you never do anything with it. Then when you start your while loop you call `mysql_fetch_array()` again, but since you've already taken the first row, it starts with the second row.

Answer (score 0):

okay you must understand why it ignore 1 row lets see  **$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());** this code fetch your 1st row already and then you fetch in loop so it pointed row after the row is already fetched.

```
 $limit  = 15;             // Set limit to show for pagination
    $page   = $_GET['page'];  // get page number from submit

    if($page) 
      $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; // first item to display on this page
    else
      $start = 0; // if no page var is given, set start to 0

    $query  = "SELECT PartyMstr.PartyMstrID, UserName, FirstName, LastName, XrefPartyRoleID
                FROM PartyMstrRole, PartyMstr
                WHERE PartyMstr.PartyMstrID = PartyMstrRole.PartyMstrID &&
                      PartyMstrRole.XrefPartyRoleID = 1 
                ORDER BY LastName, FirstName ASC
                LIMIT $start, $limit
              ";

    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalitems1 =  mysql_num_rows($result);
  ?>
  <center><h3> Admin User List </h3></center>
  <?php
    echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">";
    echo "<tr><th>PartyMaster ID</th>";
    echo "<th>UserName</th>";
    echo "<th>Last, First</th>";
    echo "<th>Link</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<tr><td>";
      echo $row['PartyMstrID'];
      echo "<td>";
      echo $row['UserName'];
      echo "<td>";
      echo " " . $row['LastName'] . ", " . $row['FirstName'] . " ";
      echo "<td>";
      echo "<a href = \"http://www.505575.com/editUser.php?id=" . $row['PartyMstrID'] . "\" >Edit</a>";

      // echo "<td>";
      // echo $row['XrefPartyRoleID'];

      echo "</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table><br/><br/> ";

    $paginaton  = getPaginationString( $page, $totalitems, $limit,
                    $adjacents  = 1,
                    $targetpage = "adminUserList.php",
                    $pagestring = "?page="
    ); // Functon found in functions.php

    echo $paginaton; 
  ?>
</td>
```